# Transcription of Jodie Foster interview. Corrections?

Tags: grammaire, expressions

I stumbled across an interview with Jodie Foster speaking French and decided to try and transcribe it. There are several words/phrases I didn't catch and there are probably plenty of errors, too. I invite anyone to offer corrections or insights. And if there's a more appropriate place to post this sort of thing, please let me know.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPc-5SbiReo

- Le cinéma accompagner [?] Jodie Foster qui est ce soir notre invitée, ce soir c’est, c’est plus la réalisatrice que l’actrise d’ailleurs qui va répondre à nos questions. Jodie Foster va nous parler du petit homme, un film quel vient de réaliser et qui a enthusiasmé le tout hollywood. On regarde toute (s)uite un petit extrait, histoire de nous mettre de l’ambiance. Voyons ça.
- [excerpt]
- Jodie Foster, bonsoir.
- Bonsoir.
- Merci d’avoir accepté notre invitation.
- Je vous en prie.
- Çe film raconte, donc, les également d’un enfant qui est un petit peu génial. Vous avez vous-même débutais sur les écrans à trois ans. Est-ce qui un petit coté autobiographie dans tout ça. Est-ce que vous vous retrouver quelque part?
- Oui, un petit peu parce que j’ai vécu quand-même une vie entre guillemets pas normale. Mais j’étais pas surdoué, je t’ai pas plus [?] que les autres c’était seulement dans un métier assez prodif [?] quoi.
- Comment ça s’est passé avec le petit garçon je pose que vous l’avez pieds, vous l’avez des salles de vous rappeler de ta souvenir, non?
- Oui, c’est vrai. Ça fait quand-même vingt-cinq ans que je suis devant le caméra, alors, j’ai puis quand-même lui donné un petit peu les experiences, mais finalement j’ai trouvé que lui, il travaille du meme façon que moi. C’était plutôt [?] du l’instant.
- Il est très naturel d’infant.
- Exactement.
- Oui. Qu’est-ce que vous pensez du phénomène des infant stars aux États Unis. Je vous pose la question parce qu’il y a plus d’enfants stars aux États Unis vous êtes bien placé pour le savoir que chez nous. Comment ça se passe?
- Oui, enfin, il faut dire que je, j’ai dû être une quand j’était petite. Oui, pourquoi pas. Moi je trouve que les histoires des enfants, c’est, sont intéressant et pourquoi pas avoir les enfants qui jouent des personnages, des vrai personnages au lieu de toujours jouer des petits objets innocents, quoi.
- Et puis ils sont très spontané, hein?
- Oui, c’est vrai.
- Ça passe bien. Alors, désormais vous êtes à la fois donc actrice et réalisatrice. Qu’est-ce qui vous tient plus à coeur en ce moment, la, sur plateau vous êtes d’abord réalisatrice ce soir?
- Oui, enfin je peux jamais choisir entre les deux, certainement pas. C’est vrai que ça prend deux partie très différents de la personnalité. Une partie celui du réalisateur qui est l’intelligence, l’analyse, tous ce qui ordre, ordinae, forme. Et puis l’autre partie qui puis spontané c’est vraiment la partie de l’actrice qui… on faire la danse, quoi.
- Parce que vous apporte beaucoup de papier beaucoup de scenario. Qu’est-ce qui fait que vous craquer pour un film plutôt pour un autre. Aussi bien d’ailleurs comme actrice comme réalisatrice.
- C’est la vérité, [c’est la mot?]. C’est vraiment, si ça son faux. J’arrive pas le faire. Alors…
- Provoquer [?] l’émotion ou la verité alors.
- Oui, ça peut [manère?] une comédie, ça n’a rien a voir avec d’humour. Mais c’est une partie, quelque chose qui est vrai, qui touche, qui mouve [?]
- Est-ce que Hollywood les gens certains hommes question pose les français que je brule d’envie de vous posé la puisque je vous tiens je vous les poser. Est-ce que Hollywood la mythe de la star est encore bien vivant.
- Oui enfin, c’est un différente mythe. Il faut dire qu’il y a deux couche finalement d’acteurs. Il y a ceux qui sont les stars, les movie stars comme on dit, et puis il y a des acteurs normale comme moi. Je pense que…
- Oh, quand meme un peu tout de la moyen. Quand on a eu un Oscar, quand meme pas madame tout le monde, non?
- Oui, mais je pense que c’est un petit peu différent. Je pense que je suis reconnu pour mon travail et pour les personnages dont je jouer, et pas tellement parce que je porte un jean et je me mets sur les journaux, c’est un petit différent.
- Parlez-moi du “Silence des Agneaux”. Vous êtes nominée je crois. [?] Je passe on dit comme ça aux états unis vous êtes nominée vous êtes encore pour les Golden Globes aux états unis pour votre role, et la vous incarné une héroine. Qu’est-ce qui vous séduit dans le personnage? C’est de coté un peu mythologique du héroine.
- Oui certainement, c’est la première fois dans le cinéma [?] je pense c’est la première fois qu’une femme partage le mythe de l’hero. Normalement c’est seulement les hommes qui vont dans le foret de les experience rencontrer les demons. C’est la première fois pour nous qu’on vraiment une femme  partager, partage cette folklore.
- Et ça s’est bien passé, enfin, c’est un film qui marche très fort.
- Il marche très fort parce que c’est un beau film parce que ça incarne aussi autant la literature, et la entertainment, le spectacle, c’est tout les deux.
- Dernière question discrete. Comment avez vous fait pour apprendre le français comme ça, pour le parle aussi bien. La vous mets pas [?].
  -Je suis allé une, un lycée français, et puis aussi j’ai passé pas mal de temps en France.
- Qu’est-ce qui vous séduit en France, plus qu’aux États Unis?
- Ça fait partie de ma personnalité, un petit peu. J’ai passé pas mal d’années de mon infance ici. Alors c’est surtout, pour moi c’est la culture, c’est la langue. C’est, quelque chose, quand je parle le français, la, pour le moment je parle pas aussi bien parce que j’ai passé très peu de temps ici, mais, mais quand je parle français pendant pas mal de temps. Je… ça me séduit, c’est la langue qui me séduit, surtout.
- Merci. Très vite parce que l’on a pris pas le temps. Si vous devez retourner en France et si vous aviez la possibilité de choisir un réalisateur ça serait qui?
- Un seul? Je ne sais pas. Toute. Surtout tout ces mythes en scène de la [?] que j’aimais tellement, Chabrole(?), le louche, loumal(?), enfin.
- Merci. Je rappelle que votre film, intitulé “Le Petit Homme” sort le quinze janvier prochaine sur les écrans. Merci, on croise les droits pour les Oscars, les Golden Globes.

Comment: Could you clarify if you are looking for a whole check, or more about points that you are unclear of? That's different, and the first one is quite long and time consuming. Note that for `Chabrole(?), le louche, loumal(?), enfin.`, it's Chabrol (for Claude Chabrol, Claude Lelouch, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, Larme, that's already really helpful. My main questions are where I've added the notation (?) or [?]. I used the first notation when I was guessing a word or writing what it sounds like, and I used the second when I had no clue. I don't expect a full check, but wouldn't be surprised if someone ends up doing it since some people seem to really enjoy this sort of thing. Any contributions appreciated.

Comment: For the first paragrpah: "Le cinéma en compagnie donc de Jodie Foster qui est ce soir notre invitée, ce soir c’est, c’est plus la réalisatrice que l’actrice d’ailleurs qui va répondre à nos questions. Jodie Foster va nous parler de *Petit Homme*, un film qu'elle vient de réaliser et qui a enthousiasmé le tout Hollywood. On regarde tout de suite un petit extrait, histoire de nous mettre de l’ambiance. Voyons ça."

Comment: "Ce film raconte, donc, les égarements d’un enfant qui est un petit enfant génial. Vous avez vous-même débuté sur les écrans à trois ans. Est-ce qu'il y un petit coté autobiographie dans tout ça. Est-ce que vous vous retrouvez, euh..., quelque part ?" I let this in comment for anyone that would fix it all. Note that in your transcript there are sometimes French errors (conjugaison, etc.), sentences that don't make sense, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my contribution, not perfect I did it quickly :

- Le cinéma **en compagnie, donc, de** Jodie Foster qui est ce soir notre invitée, ce soir c’est, c’est plus la réalisatrice que l’actrice d’ailleurs qui va répondre à nos questions. Jodie Foster va nous parler du petit homme, un film **qu'elle** vient de réaliser et qui a enth**ou**siasmé le tout hollywood. On regarde toute de suite un petit extrait, histoire de nous mettre de l’ambiance. Voyons ça.
- [excerpt]
- Jodie Foster, bonsoir.
- Bonsoir.
- Merci d’avoir accepté notre invitation.
- Je vous en prie.
- Çe film raconte, donc, les **égarements** d’un enfant qui est un petit enfant génial. Vous avez vous-même début**é** sur les écrans à trois ans. Est-ce qu **'il y a** un petit coté autobiographie dans tout ça. Est-ce que vous vous retrouver quelque part?
- Oui, un petit peu parce que j’ai vécu quand-même une vie entre guillemets pas normale. Mais j’étais pas **un** surdoué, j**’étais pas plus intelligente** que les autres c’était seulement dans un métier assez prodi**ge** quoi.
- **Alors** comment ça s’est passé avec le petit garçon je **sup**pose que vous l’avez **épié**, vous l’avez **aidé ça a dû vous** rappeler de**s** ta**s** de souvenir**s**, non?
- Ou**ais**, c’est vrai. Ça fait quand-même vingt-cinq ans que je suis devant le**s** caméra**s**, alors, j’ai puis quand-même lui donné un petit peu les experiences, mais finalement j’ai trouvé que lui, il travaille du meme façon que moi. C’était plutôt [?] du l’instant.
- Il est très naturel d’infant.
- Exactement.
- Oui. Qu’est-ce que vous pensez du phénomène des **enfants** stars aux États Unis. Je vous pose la question parce qu’il y a plus d’enfants stars aux États Unis vous êtes bien placé pour le savoir que chez nous. Comment ça se passe?
- Oui, enfin, il faut dire que je, j’ai dû être une quand j’était petite. Oui, pourquoi pas. Moi je trouve que les histoires des enfants, c’est, sont intéressant**s** et pourquoi pas avoir les enfants qui jouent des personnages, des vrai personnages au lieu de toujours jouer des petits objets innocents, quoi.
- Et puis ils sont très spontané**s**, hein?
- Oui, c’est vrai.
- Ça passe bien. Alors, désormais vous êtes à la fois donc actrice et réalisatrice. Qu’est-ce qui vous tient plus à coeur en ce moment, la, sur plateau vous êtes d’abord réalisatrice ce soir?
- Oui, enfin je **pourrai** jamais choisir entre les deux, certainement pas. C’est vrai que ça prend deux partie très différents de la personnalité. Une partie celui du réalisateur qui est l’intelligence, l’analyse, tous ce qui ordre, **ordonné**, forme. Et puis l’autre partie qui puis spontané c’est vraiment la partie de l’actrice qui… on faire la danse, quoi.
- Parce que vous apporte beaucoup de papier beaucoup de scenario**s**. Qu’est-ce qui fait que vous craque**z** pour un film plutôt pour un autre. Aussi bien d’ailleurs comme actrice comme réalisatrice.
- C’est la vérité, **finalement**. Si ça son**ne** faux. J’arrive pas **à** le faire. Alors…
- **Il faut qu'il y ait de** l’émotion ou la vérité alors.
- Oui, **et** ça peut **même être** une comédie, ça n’a rien a voir avec **l**’humour. Mais c’est une partie, quelque chose qui est vrai, qui touche, qui émouve. *(see comment below)*
- Est-ce que **à** Hollywood, **là j'ai un certain nombre de** questions que se pose**ent** les français que je brule d’envie de vous pos**er* la puisque je vous tiens je vous les poser. Est-ce que **à** Hollywood le mythe de la star est encore bien vivant **?**
- Oui enfin, c’est un différente mythe. Il faut dire qu’il y a deux couche finalement d’acteurs. Il y a ceux qui sont les stars, les movie stars comme on dit, et puis il y a des acteurs normal (should say *normaux*) comme moi. Je pense que…
- Oh, quand meme un peu tout de la moyen. Quand on a eu un Oscar, quand meme pas madame tout le monde, non?
- Oui, mais je pense que c’est un petit peu différent. Je pense que je suis reconnu**e** pour mon travail et pour les personnages dont je jouais, et pas tellement parce que je porte un jean et je me mets sur les journaux, c’est un petit différent.
- Parlez-moi du “Silence des Agneaux”. Vous êtes nominée je crois. **Non je ne sais pas si** on dit comme ça aux états unis vous êtes nominée vous êtes encore pour les Golden Globes aux états unis pour votre role, et la vous incarné une héroine. Qu’est-ce qui vous séduit dans le personnage? C’est de coté un peu mythologique du héroine.
- Oui certainement, c’est la première fois dans le cinéma **américain** je pense c’est la première fois qu’une femme partage le mythe de l’hero. Normalement c’est seulement les hommes qui vont dans le foret de les experience rencontrer les demons. C’est la première fois pour nous qu’on vraiment une femme  partager, partage cette folklore.
- Et ça s’est bien passé, enfin, c’est un film qui marche très fort.
- Il marche très fort parce que c’est un beau film parce que ça incarne aussi autant la literature, et la entertainment, le spectacle, c’est tout les deux.
- Dernière question **in**discrete. Comment avez vous fait pour apprendre le français comme ça, pour le parl**er** aussi bien. La vous **m'épatez**.
  -Je suis allé une, un lycée français, et puis aussi j’ai passé pas mal de temps en France.
- Qu’est-ce qui vous séduit en France, plus qu’aux États Unis?
- Ça fait partie de ma personnalité, un petit peu. J’ai passé pas mal d’années de mon infance ici. Alors c’est surtout, pour moi c’est la culture, c’est la langue. C’est, quelque chose, quand je parle le français, la, pour le moment je parle pas aussi bien parce que j’ai passé très peu de temps ici, mais, mais quand je parle français pendant pas mal de temps. Je… ça me séduit, c’est la langue qui me séduit, surtout.
- Merci. Très vite parce que l’on a pris pas le temps. Si vous devez retourner en France et si vous aviez la possibilité de choisir un réalisateur ça serait qui?
- Un seul? Je ne sais pas. Toute. Surtout tous ces **metteurs** en scène de la **nouvelle vague** que j’aimais tellement, [*Chabrol*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Chabrol), [**Lelouch**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Lelouch), [**Louis Malle**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Malle), enfin.
- Merci. Je rappelle que votre film, intitulé “Le Petit Homme” sort le quinze janvier prochaine sur les écrans. Merci, on croise les droits pour les Oscars, les Golden Globes.

Comment: She says "Mais c’est une partie, quelque chose qui est vrai, qui touche, qui m'*émouve*. That is a small mistake on a difficult verb (even for native speakers): it should be *qui m'émeut*. Note that she also makes a couple of other (forgivable) errors in French: it should be *du héros* (not *de l'héros*), *ce folklore* (not *cette folklore*)